# Execute external command

Tags: scala, playframework, exec

I do not know whether it is a Scala or Play! question. I want to execute some external command from my Play application, get the output from the command and show a report to user based on the command output. Can anyone help?

For example, when I enter *my-command* from shell it shows output like below, which I want to capture and show in web:

```
Id    Name   IP
====================
1     A      x.y.z.a
2     B      p.q.r.s
```

Please, do not worry about format and parsing of the output. Functionally, I am looking something like PHP *exec*. I know about java **Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command")** but is there any Scala/Play version to serve the purpose?

Comment: I thought of this idea: I need to clear the console, and well, `print("\u001b[2J")` doesn't work, it just moves the console forward over and over again when used; so I thought I would execute `clear` to clear the console without moving it!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The method `!!` of the [Scala process package](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/sys/process/index.html) does what you need, it executes the statement and captures the text output.  For example:

```
import scala.sys.process._
val cmd = "uname -a" // Your command
val output = cmd.!! // Captures the output
```

Comment: [Handy documentation link](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/#scala.sys.process.package)

Answer (score 7):

```
scala> import scala.sys.process._
scala> Process("cat temp.txt")!
```

This assumes there is a temp file in your home directory. `!` is for actual execution of the command. See scala.sys.process for more info.

Comment: What does the `_` do in the import?

Comment: New method of clearing the screen: `(Process("clear")!)` or `(Process("cls")!)`!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `Process` library: for instance

```
import scala.sys.process.Process
Process("ls").!!
```

to get the list of files in the folder as a string. The `!!` get the output of the command