# Delete from Hive table using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am using Hive 1.2.1 and Spark 1.6, and the issue is I am unable to do a simple delete operation in a Hive table using the spark shell. Since hive supports ACID since 0.14, I was hoping it would be allowed in Spark.

```
 16/01/19 12:44:24 INFO hive.metastore: Connected to metastore.


 scala> hiveContext.sql("delete from testdb.test where id=2");


 16/01/19 12:44:51 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parsing command: delete from    
 testdb.test where id=2
 16/01/19 12:44:52 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parse Completed

 org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
 Unsupported language features in query: delete from testdb.test where id=2
 TOK_DELETE_FROM 1, 0,12, 12
   TOK_TABNAME 1, 4,6, 12
    testdb 1, 4,4, 12
     test 1, 6,6, 19
     ......

 scala.NotImplementedError: No parse rules for TOK_DELETE_FROM:
 TOK_DELETE_FROM 1, 0,12, 12
 TOK_TABNAME 1, 4,6, 12
  testdb 1, 4,4, 12
  ......
```

Answer (score 1):

You could run Hive via the command line from inside Scala.

```
import scala.sys.process._
val cmd = "hive -e \"delete from testdb.test where id=2\"" // Your command
val output = cmd.!! // Captures the output
```

See also [Execute external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162483/execute-external-command)

Comment: The command that you have provided is correct and runs from command line, however it gives a ParseException when it is run from the spark-shell.                                                      FAILED: ParseException line 1:3 cannot recognize input near '<EOF>' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' in switch database statement
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 64