# Scala: run external script with dash multiple arguments

Tags: scala

As reported here [Execute external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162483/execute-external-command)
in order to run an external shell command or script in Scala the right code should be:

```
import scala.sys.process._
val cmd = "ls -l /home" // Your command
val output = cmd.!! // Captures the output
```

I've noticed this works for some commands but not for others like `"java -version"` (especially if they have dash `"-"` before arguments)

Is there a correct way to execute commands like `"python --version"` or a more complex python script like `"python /path/to/my_script.py -x value -y value"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work with dashes

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.13.6 (Eclipse OpenJ9 VM, Java 1.8.0_292).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import scala.sys.process._
import scala.sys.process._

scala> "java -version".!!
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
...

scala> "python3 --version".!!
val res1: String =
"Python 3.8.5
"
```

Comment: Yes, it works. I've fined out it was a bug of the application (Lucidworks Fusion 4.2.5) I'm using for my project.